Mapping an observable of one array to the Item array for Kendo Scroll View
I'm trying to get an array of a type of awards mapped to the Kendo Item array of title: string, location: string.
The Kendo Scroll View takes an array of items[title: string, location: string]
Here is what I'm trying to work with:
  public ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.award$ = this.servicemethods.getRecentAwardsKendo();
    this.award$.subscribe({
      next: value => this.items.map(value.forEach(s => ({title: s.awardBannerText})
    })
  }

next: does have all the awards.  I can index into the array and get any location URL, text properties.
The getRecentAwardsKendo() is the method that returns what I want the kendo scroll view to use.  It is in-mem data for 4 arwards.  Each of these has the first name, last name of the recipient, the date awarded and award banner text. I want to concatenate all these and stuff this string into the title: property. Need to also populate the location: with the imageUrl.
I can individually get all items from the array of awards returned.
What is the right way to iterate over the array returned, and map it to the Items[] array?
=========== As of 4PM 25 June =========== Here is our latest code:
       public ngOnInit(): void
    {
      this.award$ = this.servicemethods.getRecentAwardsKendo();
      this.award$.subscribe({
this.items.map(value.forEach(s => title += s.awardBannerText))
        next: value =>
        {
          console.log('Award Records prior to For Each ', value);
          value.forEach(v =>
          {
            console.log(' in for each before map loop ' + v.awardDate.toISOString() +
              ' \n ' + ' first name ' + v.employeeFirstName);
            this.items.map((m: Item) =>
            {
              console.log('in map loop' + m.title + ' \n ' + 'award date ' + v.awardDate.toISOString() +
                ' \n ' +  'first name ' + v.employeeFirstName);
              m.title = v.awardDate.toISOString() + ' ' + v.employeeFirstName, m.location = v.imageUrl
            })
          })
        }
      })
    }

The plot thickens -- here is a screen shot showing output from the console.log entries:

We are not out of the woods :) -- how is this very simple use of loops corrupting our 4 input records?
Thanks!

Too easy :), the above shows how this was overthought.
The property items: needs to be populated.  Mapping value to items is the obvious answer.
   public ngOnInit(): void
 {
   this.award$ = this.servicemethods.getRecentAwardsKendo();
   this.award$.subscribe({
     next: value =>
     {
       this.items = value.map(v => ({
         title: v.awardDate.toLocaleDateString()
           + ' ' + v.employeeFirstName
           + ' ' + v.employeeLastName
           + ' ' + v.doitTuitAwardText,
         location: v.imageUrl
       }));
     }
   })
 }

